# Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils seraient / sont bien là

Tags: conditionnel, concordance-des-temps

Bonjour,

A est dans un local, il y cherche quelque chose. Il s'approche de l'ordinateur et pense :

> Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils **seraient** bien là.

Le conditionnel est possible ici, car le sujet de la première partie et de la deuxième n'est pas le même, "salle" et "ils". Le conditionnel convient mieux que le présent "sont". Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 3):

C'est plus le sens que les règles de grammaire qui permettent de choisir le temps et le mode à utiliser.

1. On soupçonne qu'ils sont là :

> Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils seraient bien là.

ou mieux :

> Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils pourraient bien être là.

2. On est sûr qu'ils ne peuvent être que là :

> Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils sont là.

Je ne mettrais pas ***bien** là* car *bien* indique une confirmation qui est un peu en contradiction avec le *Si* du début de phrase.

Comment: Quid des mystères des mystiques ? — Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils sont là mais on ne les voit pas !

Comment: @Personne Tout ça est bien mystérieux... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pour exprimer une hypothèse, on peut employer si + imparfait --> conditionnel présent :

> Si cette salle cachait des mystères, ils seraient là.

Ce n'est pas forcement dans le passé ; c'est le concordance des temps qui gouverne le verbe de la subordonnée (la phrase avec *si*).

Pour la probabilité ou presque la certitude, si + présent --> présent de l'indicatif ou si + présent --> futur simple

> Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils sont là. 
> Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils seront là.

Comment: Merci. _Si cette salle **cachait** des mystères, ils **seraient** là._ C'est une condition irréelle, non ? En réalité, il n'y a pas de mystères dans cette salle. Je pense qu'il y a une différence entre _Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils **sont** là._ et _Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils **seraient** là._ La deuxième reflète plus d'incertitude.

Answer (score 1):

"*Si cette salle cache des mystères, ils seraient là*" est **faux**.

> **La concordance des temps avec SI**
> La subordonnée conjonctive de condition est le plus souvent introduite par "si", et il y a trois cas de "si" :
>
> - 1er cas : si + présent -> futur simple (ou présent) =>Si tu veux, je
>   viendrai / je viens. (selon le contexte)
> - 2e cas : si + imparfait ->conditionnel présent => Si tu voulais, tu pourrais.
> - 3e cas : si +plus-que-parfait ->conditionnel passé => Si tu avais voulu, tu aurais pu.

source: https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-15267.php

Ca me fait mal aux oreilles rien qu'à l'entendre, mais il est vrai que depuis quelques années, que ce soit dans à l'écrit ou à l'oral, dans les médias, et même ailleurs, le niveau global de maîtrise du Français s'enfonce dans la médiocrité... Une seule solution, la lecture, et la vraie.